# Screen layout disturbed in Tablet. Works fine on Tablet Emulator and on 5" android phone

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet

I have a screen with several input fields and two buttons centred at the bottom. On the phone it looks like:

[Phone view (looks same on tablet emulator)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnsCN.png)

But on tablet it looks like as shown below:

[On tablet device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B3hY.png)

I need a zoom version of how it looks in the phone. Like all the views (textinputlayout, buttons, font-size, hint) everything should look same but bigger on big screen sizes.
It should just zoom out on big screen and be consistent with the look on phone.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have given all the dimensions in dp and used LinearLayout as the ViewGroup. minSDKVersion is 19.

My code is as pasted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/header_left_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:weightSum="100.0"
    tools:context=".OutletDetailsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_outlet_details"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg">


    <com.admin.view.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/registerOutletHeader"
        android:layout_weight="6.0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/screenHeader"
        />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollViewRegisterBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="75.0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/floating_line">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/register_box_top_margin"
            android:id="@+id/registerContainerBox"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputOutletNameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <com.admin.view.CustomFontEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputOutletNameText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/outlet_name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:theme="@style/inputText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputaddressLine1Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <com.admin.view.CustomFontEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputaddressLine1Text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/address_line1"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:theme="@style/inputText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputaddressLine2Layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <com.admin.view.CustomFontEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputaddressLine2Text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/address_line2"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:theme="@style/inputText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputPinCodeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <com.admin.view.CustomFontEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputPinCodeText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/pin_code"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="6"
                    android:theme="@style/inputText" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputEmailLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <com.admin.view.CustomFontEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputEmailText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/email_id"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:theme="@style/inputText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputPhoneNumberLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <com.admin.view.CustomFontEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputPhoneNumberText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:theme="@style/inputText"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="19.0"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <com.admin.view.CustomFontButton
            android:id="@+id/reset_button"
            style="@style/formButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <com.admin.view.CustomFontButton
            android:id="@+id/registerOutletNextButton"
            style="@style/formButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>`enter code here`
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

THat isn't how Android is or should work.  THe tablet view is correct-  there's enough room to fit everything on there, so it all displays.  You actually don't want it to just zoom out-  things will look ugly and pixelated.  I suggest you read https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Also note that it won't look the same on all phones.  I have a 6 inch phone-  it will look somewhere between the tablet and the phone view you see.